# What first-class lawyer would use, or cite, obscure Contract Law textbooks?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

How can I salvage [What first-class lawyer would use, or cite, obscure Contract Law textbooks?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/86184)?

---

To prove treaties like *Chitty* and *Treitel* are world famous, I'm quoting citations of them by Commonwealth apex courts  OUTWITH the U.K.

At [footnote 11](http://www.nzlii.org/cgi-bin/sinodisp/nz/cases/NZSC/2011/89.html?query=%22edwin%20peel%20%22#fnB11) in [*Westpac New Zealand Ltd v MAP and Associates Ltd* [2011] NZSC 89](http://www.nzlii.org/cgi-bin/sinodisp/nz/cases/NZSC/2011/89.html?query=%22edwin%20peel%20%22#fn11), the New Zealand Supreme Court cited

> [...] HG Beale (ed) ***Chitty on Contracts*** (30th ed, Sweet & Maxwell, London, 2008) vol 1 at [7–001]; MP Furmston ***Cheshire, Fifoot and Furmston's Law of Contract*** (15th ed, Oxford University Press, Oxford, 2007) at 385–386;  Edwin Peel  ***[Treitel on] The Law of Contract*** (12th ed, Sweet and Maxwell, London, 2007) at [10–008] and [10–039]; SM Waddams ***The Law of Contracts*** (6th ed, Canada Law Book, Ontario, 2010) at 518–522

At [footnote 7](http://www.nzlii.org/cgi-bin/sinodisp/nz/cases/NZCA/2012/562.html?query=%22edwin%20peel%20%22#fnB7) in [*Planet Kids Ltd v Auckland Council* [2012] NZCA 562](http://www.nzlii.org/nz/cases/NZCA/2012/562.html), the New Zealand Court of Appeal also cited *Treitel: The Law of Contract* and *Chitty on Contracts*.

The High Court of Australia regularly cites [*Chitty*](http://www.austlii.edu.au/cgi-bin/viewdoc/au/cases/cth/HCA/2019/30.html?context=1;query=chitty;mask_path=au/cases/cth/HCA) and [*Treitel*](http://www.austlii.edu.au/cgi-bin/sinosrch.cgi?;method=auto;query=treitel%20;view=relevance&mask_path=au/cases/cth/HCA).

In [*London Drugs Ltd. v. Kuehne & Nagel International Ltd.* [1992] 3 SCR 299](https://canlii.ca/t/1fs8w), the Supreme Court of Canada cited *Anson's Law of Contract*, *Cheshire and Fifoot’s Law of Contract*, *Chitty*, Treitel.  In [*Bhasin v. Hrynew*, 2014 SCC 71](https://canlii.ca/t/gf84s), the SCC again cited *Cheshire and Fifoot’s* and *Chitty*.

## Plainly, competent lawyers would use and cite the ABOVE worthy monographs!

### 1.  Then what competent lawyer would even rely on the unknown outlandish textbooks BENEATH? What if they misrepresent the law? Then a lawyer commits professional negligence in relying on them!

### 2.  Why would a reputable publisher like OUP commission so many  of the little-known Contract Law textbooks BENEATH? How are they still on the market with so many editions? Isn't the English Contract Law textbook market OVERsaturated?

#### [Oxford University Press](https://global.oup.com/ukhe/disciplines/law/contract-law)

[TT Arvind, *Contract Law* (3rd edn, 2022)](https://global.oup.com/ukhe/product/contract-law-9780198867777).
[Ruth Akins, *Koffman, Macdonald & Atkins' Law of Contract* (10 edn, 2022)](https://global.oup.com/ukhe/product/koffman-macdonald-and-atkins-law-of-contract-9780198860907).
[Janet O'Sullivan, *O'Sullivan & Hilliard's The Law of Contract* (10 edn, 2022)](https://global.oup.com/ukhe/product/osullivan-and-hilliards-the-law-of-contract-9780192856555).
[Séverine Saintier, *Poole's Casebook on Contract Law* (15 edn, 2021)](https://global.oup.com/ukhe/product/pooles-casebook-on-contract-law-9780198869986).
[Séverine Saintier, *Poole's Textbook on Contract Law* (15 edn, 2021)](https://global.oup.com/ukhe/product/pooles-textbook-on-contract-law-9780198869993).
[Paul S. Davies, *JC Smith's The Law of Contract* (3 edn, 2021)](https://global.oup.com/ukhe/product/jc-smiths-the-law-of-contract-9780198853503).
[André Naidoo, *Complete Contract Law Text, Cases, and Materials* (2021)](https://global.oup.com/ukhe/product/complete-contract-law-9780198749868).

#### Other Publishers

[Roger Brownsword, *Smith & Thomas: A Casebook on Contract* (14 edn, Sweet & Maxwell, 2021)](https://www.sweetandmaxwell.co.uk/Product/Academic-Law/Smith-and-Thomas-A-Casebook-on-Contract/Paperback/42597907).
[James Devenney, *The Modern Law of Contract* (14 edn, Routledge, 2022)](https://www.routledge.com/The-Modern-Law-of-Contract/Stone-Devenney/p/book/9780367697952).
[James Devenney, *Text, Cases and Materials on Contract Law* (15 edn, Routledge, 2023)](https://www.routledge.com/Text-Cases-and-Materials-on-Contract-Law/Stone-Devenney/p/book/9780367222956).
[Paul Richards, *Law of Contract* (14 edn, Pearson, 2020)](https://www.pearson.com/en-gb/subject-catalog/p/law-of-contract/P200000005303/9781292251516).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I salvage What first-class lawyer would use, or cite, obscure Contract Law textbooks??

In the comments to that post some of us already gave you suggestions for improvement. It is unclear why you ask now on LawMeta instead of following those suggestions first.

[Rick](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/86184/what-first-class-lawyer-would-use-or-cite-obscure-contract-law-textbooks#comment192281_86184) and [I](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/86184/what-first-class-lawyer-would-use-or-cite-obscure-contract-law-textbooks#comment192232_86184) explained that the questions in item 2 are off-topic. They pertain to a publishers' *discretion* in how they exercise their freedom of contract. Those questions are not about law.

In turn, [Tiger Guy](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/86184/what-first-class-lawyer-would-use-or-cite-obscure-contract-law-textbooks#comment192488_86184) suggested you not to use heading fonts. He reflected that your use of heading fonts is perceived as "*scream[ing] at us*". Even here on LawMeta you are reproducing that post using heading fonts.

An [earlier version](https://law.stackexchange.com/revisions/86184/4) of your post reads "*What if the books BENEATH misrepresent the law, and the lawyer commits professional negligence?*". You subsequently changed the latter part to the emphatic conclusion that "*Then a lawyer commits professional negligence in relying on them!*", which warrants [clarifying](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/86184/what-first-class-lawyer-would-use-or-cite-obscure-contract-law-textbooks#comment192274_86184) that "*a lawyer ought to rely on the actual statutes and legal precedents, not really on what other books --whether or not renowned-- say about those authorities*". That edit does not make your post more off-topic or less off-topic, but phrasing that as an emphatic conclusion suggests that you have a preconceived idea and will reject any answer that does not align with that preconception.

The only suggestions you did follow pertain to [JBentley](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/86184/what-first-class-lawyer-would-use-or-cite-obscure-contract-law-textbooks#comment192226_86184)'s discrepancy regarding the reputation of some of the titles you listed. However, that issue is irrelevant to the only portion of your post that is on topic: The relation between a book publisher's misrepresentation and the extent to which a lawyer incurs negligence by relying on those books.

I am the one who voted to reopen your post. But one vote is not enough, and you are unlikely to prompt others to reopen your post if you stick to the version you reproduced here.